# dynamic module : Ipv4 configurator does not assign address to the dynamic module omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have created a dynamic module using this code below. The module is created successfully but the ipv4configurator module did not assign an IP address to the created dynamic module. So when I run the simulation, I get this error:

" ASSERT: Condition '!myIPAddress.isUnspecified()' does not hold in function 'sendArpRequest' at inet/networklayer/arp/ipv4/Arp.cc:173 -- in module (inet::Arp) Drones.clone.ipv4.arp (id=323), at t=1.057126851753s, event #272 "

```
moduleType = cModuleType::get("inet.node.inet.WirelessHost");
module = moduleType->create("clone", this);
module->finalizeParameters();
module->buildInside();
module->scheduleStart(simTime() + updateInterval);
cPreModuleInitNotification pre;
pre.module = module;
emit(POST_MODEL_CHANGE, &pre);
module->callInitialize();
cPostModuleInitNotification post;
post.module = module;
emit(POST_MODEL_CHANGE, &post);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a limitation of the `Ipv4Configurator`. It needs to know the network topology in advance to be able to assign IP addresses, optimize subnet masks and set up routing table entries.

The global `IpV4NetworkConfigurator` builds up a database first and then each node looks into this database during the setup and pulls the information related to itself and sets up the interfaces and routing tables etc.